# Draw the scatter plot using custom label using core plot

Tags: swift, graph, core-plot

I am using the scatter plot to draw the lines and custom label on x axis. I want some of the lines to start exactly form the y axis and some form custom label location.PFA the image.[image]

The control line should start from the y axis and should go till "Sat" and data line should start form "Sun" and should draw till "Sat". 
Can any one help me with how to achieve this

EDIT 1:-
As suggested by Eric i tried with 2 record for the control line and for the data lines, for Plot x i am returning the ticklocation array of the x Axis and for plot y i am returning the y value of the graph. By doing this Control lines are proper but for data lines is always starting from zero. PFA the attached image[image]

Here is the code i am writing for creating the labels on x axis

```
if(self.axisArray.count == 7) {
                tickLocation = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
            }
            else {
                tickLocation = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
            }

            var xLocations = [NSNumber]()
            var labelLocation: Int = -1
            for number in tickLocation {
                labelLocation += 1
                let newLabel = CPTAxisLabel.init(text: axisArray[labelLocation] as? String, textStyle: axisLabelStyle)
                newLabel.tickLocation = number as! NSNumber
                newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength
                xLocations.append(NSNumber(value: number as! Double))
                customLabel.append(newLabel)
            }
            x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicy.none
            x.axisLabels = Set(customLabel)
            x.majorTickLocations = Set(xLocations)
```

For the data source below is the code

```
func numberOfRecords(for plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt
    {
        if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kUpperControlLineIdentifier) {
            return UInt(2)
        }
        else if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kLowerControlLineIdentifier) {
            return UInt(2)
        }
        else if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kFirstGraphIdentfifier) {
           return UInt(self.beforeMealData.count)
        }
        else if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kSecondGraphIdentfifier) {
            return UInt(self.afterMealData.count)
        }
        else {
            return UInt(0)
        }
    }

    func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field: UInt, record: UInt) -> Any?
    {
        let plotField = CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(field))
        if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kUpperControlLineIdentifier) {
            if(plotField == .X) {
                    return Int(record)
            }
            else if(plotField == .Y) {
                    return 6
            }
        }
        else if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kLowerControlLineIdentifier) {
            if(plotField == .X) {
                return Int(record)
            }
            else if(plotField == .Y) {
                    return 5.2
            }
        }
            if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kFirstGraphIdentfifier) {
                if(plotField == .X) {
                    return self.tickLocation[Int(record)] as! NSNumber
                }
                else if(plotField == .Y) {
                    return self.afterMealData[Int(record)]
                }
            }
            else if(plot.identifier as! String == BloodGlucoseGraphView.kSecondGraphIdentfifier) {
                if(plotField == .X) {
                    return self.tickLocation[Int(record)] as! NSNumber
                }
                else if(plotField == .Y) {
                    return self.beforeMealData[Int(record)]
                }
            }
        return nil
    }
```

But then also the data lines are starting from zero not form "Sun". @Eric can you please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

For the data lines, make sure the x-values returned from the datasource match the tick location for the corresponding x-axis label. From the picture, it looks like an off-by-one error.

For the control lines, these only need two data points, one for each end of the line. The left point should have an x-value of the `location` of the plot space `xRange` and the right point should have an x-value of the `end` of the `xRange`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question again with the code. Can you please look at it and help me.

Comment: What is the `xRange` for the plot space? Also, the x-values for the data lines are wrong. Try `return (record * self.tickLocation.count) as! NSNumber`. (I didn't test this—you might need some casts in there.)

Comment: the x and y range is like this plotSpace.xRange = CPTPlotRange(location: 0, length: NSNumber.init(value: self.axisArray.count))
        plotSpace.yRange = CPTPlotRange(location: yMin, length: range) and i tried the solution like "return (Int(record) * self.tickLocation.count) as NSNumber" mentioned in the comment. it is still starting from 0 only.

Comment: My suggestion was for the control lines only. The code in the question looks ok for the data lines. Is there anywhere else the `tickLocation` array could be changed? Try logging the return x-values for the data line to see if they are what you expect.

Comment: I did for control lines and control lines are starting from "Sat" and ending at "Fri". I logged the x value of data line and it is returning correct value.